# Azure Cloud Service stops saving to table storage when storage is accessed in visual studio server explorer

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-table-storage

I am working on an azure cloud service that has two different worker roles saving entities to an azure table storage. When I run the solution locally (both in debug and release mode) it works perfectly, however when I deploy the solution (either in debug or release) to the Azure Cloud Production Environment it writes the correct data and works well; but after I open the storage account in the server explorer in visual studio to review what was saved, then the cloud service worker roles stop saving new data to the tables.

Does accessing the azure storage account from the server explorer window in visual studio freeze the storage account when an azure cloud service is running against it?

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible. Could you please provide more description about how the worker role "stop saving new data to table"? Did it encountered failures? If so, what's the detailed error message? Or did it make no progress while writing table entities?

Comment: The actual worker role, did not crash or throw an any errors (I am tracking the errors with application insights) rather it saves a few thousand entities and continues to run but the saving stops. the entities themselves are small only a few hundred bytes each.

Comment: it only seems to stop saving after I access server explorer to see what was saved, then no additional data is saved.